# Firebase Cloud Functions bitly example throwing error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm following the example from the github repository to short a link url

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/url-shortener

The error is giving is the following

> 12:49:56.472 a. m. shortenUrl Function execution took 509 ms, finished
>   with status: 'error' 12:49:56.464 a. m. shortenUrl  RequestError:
>   Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api-ssl.bitly.com:443
>       at new RequestError (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
>       at Request.plumbing.callback (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
>       at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
>       at self.callback (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Request.onRequestError (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)

I'm really new at functions but I did follow all the steps from the documentation there.

here is my index.js inside my functions folder

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const BitlyClient = require('bitly');
// TODO: Make sure to set the bitly.access_token cloud functions config using the CLI.
const bitly = BitlyClient(functions.config().bitly.access_token);

// Shorten URL written to /links/{linkID}.
exports.shortenUrl = functions.database.ref('/links/{linkID}').onCreate(async (snap) => {
  const originalUrl = snap.val();
  const response = await bitly.shorten(originalUrl);
  return snap.ref.set({
    original: originalUrl,
    short: response.data.url,
  })
});
```

and my package.json in order to compile the the neccesary for bitly

```
{
  "name": "url-shortener-functions",
  "description": "URL Shortener Firebase Functions sample",
  "dependencies": {
    "bitly": "^5.1.7",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I also did `npm -install bitly` inside my functions folder but still throwing that error

Also I added my link inside my database as the documentation states

```
/functions-project-12345
    /links
        link-123456: "https://my.super.long-link.com/api/user/profile/-jEHitne10395-k3593085"
```

Any clue ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it complains, that it cannot resolve for the remote host:

```
RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api-ssl.bitly.com:443
```

therefore I'd assume, that a [paid plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) is required, in order to perform this external API call.

Comment: hmm, weird because I generated the access token like it says from that doc

Comment: also is my first function ever made

Comment: @Todd and which plan you have for Firebase; got billing enabled?

Comment: @Todd you cannot make this call then, because it's an external API call. see the above link. it reads `Outbound networking: Google services only` (which does not include `bitly.com`).